# Only 1 screen saver actually works

Tags: windows-10

All the latest updates applied and restarted.

Windows 10 pro
System Boot Time:          12/25/2021, 4:43:22 PM
System Manufacturer:       ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
System Model:              ZenBook UX534FTC_UX534FT
System Type:               x64-based PC

For some reason my normally selected screen saver (mystify) will not work and the only one that will is the "photos" option.  What can I check?

[**update**]
[image]

Comment: In the settings does the preview button work? In a command prompt, in case it gives an error, type `mystify.src`. Does that work.

Comment: No, preview only works on the "Photos" screensaver.  No error is generated when I try preview on the others, but mystify.src from a command prompt gives " is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Also, I checked the event logs and didnt seem to spot any errors.

Comment: In a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) window, does `assoc .scr` reveal **.scr=scrfile**?  And does `assoc scrfile` reveal **scrfile=Screen saver**?  I've seen cases in the past where text editors and developer tools can steal the .scr file extension.

Comment: Yes to both questions

Comment: In a command prompt type the following. `dir c:\windows\system32\mystfy.scr` and also `set p` - check that system32 is in the path

Comment: Note Its called Mystify for a reason.

Comment: dir c:\windows\system32\mystfy.scr  File Not Found

Comment: Find a copy from another computer and put into system32 as admin.

Comment: Update in post above.  Just browsing with windows explorer.  Hmmm?